# Mongodb search without special character

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a field with value contain `.` at any position like this
"CAR201T.BA0766", "CAR20.1TBA0766".
How to get documents by searching "CAR201TBA0766"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is already processed you can just use this regex, this will allow multiple `.` within the string though:

```
const reg = /C\.?A\.?R\.?2\.?0\.?1\.?T\.?B\.?A\.?0\.?7\.?6\.?6/;
db.collection.findOne({ field: reg });
```

The `\.?` portion that is added between every single letter searches for either one `.` or zero dots. That is why multiple dots could appear (max 1 between each pair of letters).

---

The more "proper" solution to this problem is to sanitize the values before they are saved in the DB, if it's custom logic You would need to built something custom, but if what you require is just OOB "search engine" capabilities there are existing services that give it with with many more capabilities. (like elasticsearch or Mongo Atlas search).

I would recommend you do this as I consider it the better approach.